# Regex match to check US State Code exist in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am large set of array from which I am trying to find the address

For example this(State Code :- CO)

```
0 Site Address, San Luis, CO 81152
```

Now to match this I am using this regex expression :-

```
e.match(/, CO \d/)
```

How can I incorporate many statecode in it like if I have to check for this(State Code :- NM)

```
2 X Valley Rd X P2, Questa, NM 87556
```

Any address state code can come, so I want it to dynamic to check all the state codes

Please suggest

Comment: Try with the following regex: `, [A-Z]{2} \d{5}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most basic way to capture any state code would be to include a capture group with all the values you need to match.

Ex:

```
e.match(/, (CO|NM|TN|MO) \d/)
```

Wrap the different state options in parentheses, and use the pipe symbol to indicate "or".

If you have all the state codes in an array you could dynamically create this capture group.

ex:

```
const states = [
  "TN",
  "NM",
  "CO",
]

const regexStr = states.join("|")
const stateMatch = new RegExp(`, (${regexStr}) \d`)

e.match(stateMatch)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following regex:

```
, [A-Z]{2} \d{5}
```

It checks for symbols in the following succession:

- `,` : a comma + a space
- `[A-Z]{2}`: two letters
- : a space
- `\d{5}`: five digits

This approach will generalize on the state codes.